# Bash: How to force not to ignore null bytes

Tags: bash, null, byte

I want to put exactly `\xc0Ib\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00\xd5N_\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00` as a command parameter, but unfortunetly bash is ignoring null-bytes:

```
warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
```

How can I force bash not to ignore those null bytes?

Comment: You can't. But you can send them to stdin of your script (e.g. via `printf '\xc0Ib\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00\xd5N_\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00`).

Comment: Parameters are passed as [C-strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling#Definitions), and C-strings are terminated by null bytes and therefore cannot contain null bytes. This isn't a bash thing, it's how the OS handles parameters. So, yeah, you just plain can't do that.